# How to display a textbox value in a DIV multiple Times

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to display the value in a textbox in a div on keyup. I am having trouble displaying the value multiple times
Need to load the textbox value once i entered in multiple DIV. its showing in only one DIV ( first one )
This is my html and jquery code.

```
<input type="textarea" id="mytextarea"></textarea>
<div id="preview"></div>
<div id="preview"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {    
  var content = $('#mytextarea').val();
  $('#mytextarea').keyup(function () {
      if ($('#mytextarea').val() != content) {
          content = $('#mytextarea').val().replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");
          $('#preview').text(content);            
       }
  });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MyZgX/4/ this is my fiddle link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said before you can't have the same id multiple time. I suggest you to switch to a class (that can be shared amongst multiple elements)

HTML

```
<input type="textarea" id="mytextarea"></input>
<div class="preview_class" id="preview1"></div>
<div class="preview_class" id="preview2"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {    

  var content = $('#mytextarea').val();

  $('#mytextarea').keyup(function () {

      if ($('#mytextarea').val() != content) {
          content = $('#mytextarea').val().replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");

          $('.preview_class').each(function(){$(this).text(content)});            
       }
  });
});
```

Comment: This wont solve my problem :) anyway any suggestion for my question. i m getting a value in a textbox in a form. i need to display the same value inside the form in DIV / Span any idea how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can't have multiple items with the same id. Give each div the same class and use that.

```
<textarea type="textarea" id="mytextarea"></textarea>
<div class="preview"></div>
<div class="preview"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {    

  var content = $('#mytextarea').val();

  $('#mytextarea').keyup(function () {

      if ($('#mytextarea').val() != content) {
          content = $('#mytextarea').val().replace(/\\n/g, "<br />");

          $('.preview').text(content);            
       }
  });
});
```

Comment: its a form. so if anyone enters a value in the beginning we can avoid typing it again n again. i tried with many options. any clue how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Malformed HTML, for a start...

```
<input type="textarea" id="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

That should simply be:

```
<textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
```

That HTML's being interpreted in the document tree like this:

```
<input type="text" id="mytextarea" />
```

Probably might be having an impact on jQuery... ;)